# Building R packages from source fails in terminal but works in RGui on Windows Server

Tags: r

Recently I stumbled upon an interesting problem for R 4.1 installed on Windows Server. When I use RGui I could build packages from source without any problems (same in RStudio), however when I try to do the same directly in terminal, I'm getting compilation erros (various!). I checked packages: `curl`, `digest`, `jsonlite`, `rlang`, all in the latest CRAN version, below I'm pasting snippets for each.

```
* installing *source* package 'curl' ...
** package 'curl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
rm -f curl.dll callbacks.o curl.o download.o escape.o fetch.o findport.o form.o getdate.o handle.o ieproxy.o init.o interrupt.o multi.o nslookup.o options.o reflist.o split.o ssl.o typechecking.o utils.o version.o winidn.o writer.o
make: *** [Makevars.win:15: clean] Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'curl'
```

```
* installing *source* package 'digest' ...
** package 'digest' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I.         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c SpookyV2.cpp -o SpookyV2.o
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:245: SpookyV2.o] Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'digest'
```

```
* installing *source* package 'jsonlite' ...
** package 'jsonlite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api       -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c base64.c -o base64.o
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:238: base64.o] Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'jsonlite'
```

```
* installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I./rlang/         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c capture.c -o capture.o
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:238: capture.o] Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
```

I've observed this for the first time after CPUs have been added, so I guess it is related. But how, and how could I fix it? I've already reinstalled RTools, but I'd prefer NOT to reinstall R itself if possible. Any hint would be appreciated.

Error message suggests that it has something to do with `Makeconf`, so I'm pasting relevant lines (237-245).

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.c.d:
    @echo "making $@ from $<"
    @$(CC) -std=gnu99 -MM $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< > $@
.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

System details:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server x64 (build 17763)
```

Comment: This **strongly** suggests that the GUI calls invoke arguments (switches) that you are not including on the command-line call.   You can either dive into the source code of the GUI or, much easier,  post this question to the   r-sig-mac  mailing list.  Simon is very good about discussing compilation issues.